# Comma use: Two variables, A and B, were examined in separate models

Tags: commas, appositives, software-bugs

Grammarly recommends removing the second comma but for me it seems that this is needed. What would be the correct comma use in such a sentence?

> Two variables, fracture type and management method, were examined in separate models since certain fractures are treated with specific operation methods.

Comment: Grammarly won't know if you're writing a list or using a noun phrase in apposition. Do what you think is correct, not what it tells you.

Comment: You need the commas because this is a [nonrestrictive appositive](https://www.englishgrammar101.com/module-9/verbals-and-phrases/lesson-9/restrictive-and-nonrestrictive-appositives).

Comment: @GArthurBrown Wouldn't you say there's a restrictive appositive in 'Two of the children, John and Anne, are still at nursery'?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Sure. What's the got to do with the price of tea?

Comment: @GArthurBrown Your English Grammar reference states baldly 'A restrictive appositive ... is not separated from the rest of the sentence by commas.'

Comment: Useful comments! I read the link provided. As there can be other variables among the two named, I should use no commas.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth You are right, I was only reading the nonrestrictive section. Is there a source that covers this properly? All the rule-of-thumb sites imply restrictive will never use commas.

Comment: @GArthurBrown There's probably an article on appositives which classes [the boys] [,]  [Tim and Tom] [,] differently from  [two of the boys,] [Tim and Tom,]. I've never found a convincing analysis of appositives (though I've come across conflicting terminology).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Interesting, now that you point it out.